# Properly Compressing KML File in Linux

Tags: gzip, kml, google-earth

I am trying to compress a KML file using gzip on a Linux system

**Linux Code**

```
gzip -cvf somefile.kml > somefile.kmz
```

When I go to try and verify the new KMZ file in Google Earth, I receive the following error:

*Open of file "somefile.kmz" failed: Parse error at line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)*

What happened?

Comment: use zip, not gzip. (from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives): "Linux has command line versions of zip and unzip")

Answer (score 2):

Shout-out to @geocodezip for the help:

**Terminal Code**

```
zip -9 somefile.zip somefile.kml
mv -f somefile.zip somefile.kmz
```

-9 is for best zip compression

This process can also be optimized by running:

```
zip -9 somefile.kmz somefile.kml
```